How can I std::move a vector into a lambda function?
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


int main() {
    std::vector<int> integers = {0, 1, 2};

    std::function<void()> lambda = [integers] {
        printf("vector size (in lambda function): %zu\n", integers.size());
    };

    printf("vector size (in main()): %zu\n", integers.size());

    lambda();

    return 0;
}

In this simple program, vector integers is sent into a lambda function by copy, so it is unchanged after this lambda function created.
Now how do I destroy/clear this vector the same moment it sent into this lambda function? Like when a vector is sent into a function by std::move()?
The closet solution I have so far is to achieve above is:
std::vector<int> integers = {0, 1, 2};

std::function<void()> lambda = [integers] {
    printf("vector size (in lambda function): %zu\n", integers.size());
};
integers.clear();

printf("vector size (in main()): %zu\n", integers.size());

lambda();

But even so, the vector is still cleared AFTER lambda function created.
So how do I destroy this vector the moment when lambda function created?

why do you want to destroy the original vector?

Pass it as an argument instead of capturing it?

On a different note, unless you need to store the function somewhere else (as a callback in a class for example) then there's no need for std::function. In this case, just use auto type deduction.

Also, auto mylambda = [](){/* your code*/}; is a shorthand alternative if you want to call a lambda as in mylambda().

You will be laughing, but [integers=std::move(integers)]. demo

What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think "destroying" the vector at lambda creation will solve that problem? This is very much an XY problem.

@Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your reply, in my actual user case, such lambda function is sent to a threadpool that accepts std::function<void()> jobs only, so I don't see an easy way to do so other than creating a lambda function.

moving from the vector will not "destroy" the vector. Not even close. The vector is still intact afterwards, in a moved-from state

The std::move function doesn't move anything. It casts the argument to a rvalue reference type.

While C++11 only allows references or copied values in lambda captures, C++14 introduces Lambda capture expressions.  You can move your vector in one of these expressions.
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>    

int main() {
    std::vector<int> integers = {0, 1, 2};

    std::function<void()> lambda = [integers=std::move(integers)] {
                       // Initializing move ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       std::printf("vector size (in lambda function): %zu\n", integers.size());
    };

    std::printf("vector size (in main()): %zu\n", integers.size());

    lambda();

    return 0;
}

See it work.

vector size (in main()): 0
vector size (in lambda function): 3

